# Gaming Questions of the Week #7

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Previous Questions of the Week:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second week's question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- Third week's question - [Tips for not getting lost underground](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/get-lost)
- Fourth week's question - [Does GLaDOS hate Atlas, the Blue Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20540/3015)
- Fifth week's questions - [10 Awesome things to try in Minecraft](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/09/10-awesome-things-to-try-in-minecraft/)
- Fifth week's questions - [Why should I pay for that game?](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/17/why-should-i-pay-for-that-game/)

Please post any of **this week's questions** that you feel is of worth and the reason why. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Comment: Fifth week?....

Comment: @Stuart, that's what I get for copy-pasting. But we did end up blogging about the 5th week twice. And we don't have a post about the 6th one yet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next week will be probably dominated by `The-Witcher-2`, but this week it seems that

[What is a "pixel shader"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/what-is-a-pixel-shader)

got a tons of votes and good answers too.

Or maybe

[Is Megaman left or right handed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-megaman-left-or-right-handed)

Comment: It would be nice to have one of the Game Dev's write about Pixel Shader.

Comment: Please not the second one.  Its such a pointless question...

Comment: I've asked Third to write a blog post about Pixel Shaders, but I might have to ask someone else from Game Dev to help out.

Comment: I would be honoured. I'm still new to StackExchange, but I'll try to write something interesting. I'm a Digital/Software Engineer by trade, so the anything I write will be biased towards the technical aspects of Pixel Shaders (as you might've noticed in the answer above. ;) ) It would be wonderful if someone from GameDev could add some perspective on their actual use in the field. I'll try to put a draft together this evening (CET).